# Dynamic computed property inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to assign a value to `v-model` based on a dynamic computed property inside a `v-for` loop. Check this example.

```
<template>
    <template v-for="field in fields">
        <custom-input v-model="field.name"></custom-input>
    </template>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [{'name': 'foo'}]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    foo: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.foo
      },
      set(value) {
        return this.$store.commit('updateFoo', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

So the `v-model` should be bound to the computed `foo` property. If I directly assign `foo` to the `v-model` everything works, but if the name of the property is dynamically calculated, it doesn't. Can someone explain me how I can correctly implement that?

Answer (score -1):

i think this should work

```
<template v-for="field in fields">
    <custom-input v-model="computedValue"></custom-input>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [{'name': 'foo'}]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    foo: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.foo
      },
      set(value) {
        return this.$store.commit('updateFoo', value)
      }
    },
    computedValue(){
        return this[this.fields.name] //or your dynamic variable
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work. You are assuming that `fields` only has one element, but there could be more. That's why I am using a `v-for`. So actually you need to pass `field.name` to `computedValue`. But it is not allowed to pass arguments to computed properties.

Comment: it was an example, you can try 2 things,
 -use computedValue() as a method,
- create a prop in the data that reflect the name of the field that you want

Comment: The thing is that v-model does not accept a method.

Comment: I think the only solution would be to create another custom component which acts as a wrapper for the `custom-input` component.